# missing dependency detected during test using scalamock

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, scalamock

I'm trying to use scalamock / scalatest and I always have an error during testing

My build.sbt

```
name := "name"

organization := "org"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature", "-language:postfixOps","-language:existentials")

libraryDependencies <<= scalaVersion { scala_version =>
  val sparkVersion = "1.5.1"
  Seq(
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.5" % "test",
    "org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-scalatest-support" % "3.2" % "test",
    "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % "test",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
    "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0"
  )
}
```

My unit test :

```
@Test
class BWPMDAOTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with  MockFactory{
  val sparkcontext = mock[SparkContext]
  val dao = new BWPMDAO(sparkcontext)
  dao.getStatsAsList() should not be null
  dao.getStatsAsList() should not be empty
}
```

When I run `sbt test` I have the following error:

```
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'MetricsSystem.class'.
Could not access term eclipse in package org,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'MetricsSystem.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.
```

How can I solve that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I added a jetty dependency e.g. for sbt `"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-servlet" % "9.3.9.v20160517"` and then it worked.